# VertrigoServ Apache HTTP Server Port 80 Already In Use

Tags: apache, http, port

I have recently installed VertrigoServ, with the Apache HTTP Server, expecting to work perfectly like other installations. Unfortunately, this time it has not. Apache says the port 80 is already in use; I have tried all the methods suggested in other forums, but there seems to be no service, program or process using port 80.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

yes skype do clash with vertrigo just exit skype in tray icon and restart vertrigo you will be good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Vertrigo / Settings / Program Settings / Unckeck "Run servers as services", then restart your PC and start vertrigo again

Answer (score 0):

In my case case icon was yellow in Vertrigo because of running
Web Deployment Agent Service
which came probably with Microsoft WebMatrix, it is also run and probably installed by Microsoft Visual Community for example.
Changing Start type of this Service from Automatic to Manual is good solution ? 
Here:
http://www.sitepoint.com/unblock-port-80-on-windows-run-apache/
is such advice. Today it was turned off using simply Task Manager, but maybe this too brutal way.
The Run servers as services in Vertrigo is unchecked, but Web Deployment Agent Service was blocking Vertrigo.
Microsoft Matrix can run php too.

Comment: Today pressing Stop (and later Start) of the World Wide Web Publishing Service (IIS World Wide Web Publishing Service (W3SVC)) helped.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change the port that Vertrigo uses to run php pages. It worked for me, I did like this (changed to 8080):
https://sourceforge.net/p/vertrigo/discussion/2083479/thread/e8546bc9/